# Unable to access the backend/ configuration in JCE Editor

Tags: joomla

In my joomla site the JCE Pro2.6.19 is used.I am unable to access back-end & configurations in the editor. There is an error message displaying. My jommla version is Joomla! 3.9.8 
So, I need immediate assistance to fix the problem.

Error message,

Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/html/administrator/includes/toolbar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/html/administrator/components/com_jce/controller.phpon line 134

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/html/administrator/includes/toolbar.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/html/administrator/components/com_jce/controller.php on line 134

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file:

```
/administrator/includes/helper.php
```

above "*class JAdministratorHelper*" add :

```
if(!class_exists('JToolbarHelper')) {
require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/includes/toolbar.php';
}
```

or you can try this fix :
https://answers.themler.io/articles/173620/how-to-fix-the-error-after-updating-to-joomla-3-9

Comment: Thanks for your support. But I can not fixed. When I added your code on helper.php my joomla administrator panel is not working.

Comment: oh okay, then try the second method please

Comment: I think its not a template error. I can not access the JCE editor configuration panel only.

Comment: if still not working, try to call this file : require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/includes/subtoolbar.php';" in the controller line 134 instead of toolbar.php  , also look in your includes folder if file exist before

Comment: did you try to get toolbar.php from backup and put it in the folder ? it can also do the trick